# Linker Error: undefined reference to `internal'

Tags: linker, linker-errors, d, ld

I'm writing an application in D which interfaces with OpenGL and a few other native libraries (using the Derelict libraries). However, this error does not seem to relate to that at all.

Whenever I do "dub build" the compilation succeeds, but ld fails with this message:

```
Linking...
../git/mango-engine/bin/libmango-engine.a(gl_model_503_284.o):(.data._D12mango_engine8graphics6opengl8gl_model7GLModel6__initZ+0x10):     undefined reference to `internal'
../git/mango-engine/bin/libmango-engine.a(shader_51b_52f.o):    (.data._D12mango_engine8graphics6shader13ShaderProgram6__initZ+0x18):     undefined reference to `internal'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have no idea what this means, and have never seen it before. Also, strangely this error only occurs when I import the specific files: gl_model.d and shader.d, from another DUB project. If they are not imported the linker succeeds.

I'm not sure what information to provide, so I will just link the whole source code [here.](https://github.com/jython234/mango-engine)

EDIT: This error only occurs when compiling for x86_64. **x86 works fine.**

Comment: There's a function or variable likely marked `extern(C) void internal()` or something like that which is declared but not defined.. that `mango_engine.graphics` module, is it your code or from a library?

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe I only have one extern statement in the whole project, and it does have an implementation. It is also not named anywhere near "internal"

Answer (score 0):

I've tracked it down to two lines in the two files (both are the same):

```
private SyncLock lock = new SyncLock();
```

Where SyncLock is an empty class that I use for "synchronized" blocks (not sure if this is the right way to do this). For some reason, if I move the initialization to the constructor it works fine (no errors).

Comment: Initialization of a class member is totally different than a constructor... a class member is *statically* initialized, meaning the `new SyncLoc()` is run at compile time, and a pointer to a single object in data is made part of the class initializer... meaning ALL instances of the class will share the single, static instance of SyncLock. A constructor is the way to do it if each instance should be separate (almost always what you want). I still don't understand why there's an `internal` symbol in there, but `private Object x = new Object();` is almost always a newbie mistake anyway.

Comment: And generally you can do whatever you want without using lock, if you write your program in a proper concurrent manner. Lock-free programming is the way to go, because locks are an expensive work-around, for something you most likely could work around.